# JAVA BOXLAYOUT Элементы располагаются не подряд

Tags: java, swing

Элементы на моем BOXLAYOUT располагаются не последовательно, а так как на изображении.
Это из-за чего так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
jyki.setBackground(Color.white);
jyki.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jyki, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Вот так указываю layout.;

Если продолжать добавлять элементы со временем все заполнится

Полный код

```
JPanel more = new JPanel();
more.setLayout(new BoxLayout(more, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(more);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Добавление элементов на панель

```
private void addiditionals(JPanel more) {
    
    more.removeAll();
    more.revalidate();
    more.repaint();
    more.setBackground(Color.white);
    BoxLayout layout=new BoxLayout(more, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS); 
    more.setLayout(layout);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < dopolnit.size(); i ++) {
        
        JPanel uno = new JPanel();
        uno.setLayout(null);
        uno.setBackground(Color.white);
        uno.setSize(w, h);

        more.add(uno);
    }
}
```

Каждая строка - это элемент, который должен идти друг за другом, но почему-то при добавлении элементов, между ними(по вертикале) куча пространства

Comment: а разве вам там не нужно родительский Layout указывать? (уж не помню точно, давно со свингом не возился)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да нет, вроде

Comment: а что вы ожидаете?
не можете словами в вопросе описать точнее, а то не очень понятно...
вы хотите чтобы они все в линию выстроились?
если да, то `BoxLayout` на скриншоте себя ведет в целом ровно так как должен

Comment: плюс было бы неплохо код весь показать

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы между вертикальными элементами(это JPANEL )не было расстояний

Comment: а можно полный код с `newType`, `more`,`w`,`h`,`dopolnit`?

Comment: @МихаилРебров newType простой JCheckBOX
w,h константы по 25 . Dopolnit List<String> там только текст, more добавил в впорос